# Rubymine does not autocomplete paths where the resource is plural

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-routing, rubymine, code-completion

Let's say I have the following routes:

```
resources :users do
  collection do
    get :welcome
    get :search
  end
  member do
    post: invite
    post :block
  end
end
```

Then if I type `invite_u`, rubymine suggests: `invite_user_path`. Good.

But if I type: `welcome_u`, rubymine suggests: `welcome_user_path`. Not good. It should be `welcome_users_path`. Why rubymine gets it wrong ?

Comment: Are you sure it's incorrect? I always get confused with when Rails wants singular vs. plural. Can you do a `rake routes` to show your resulting routing table?

Comment: I created an app with these routes and am getting the same result as you in Rubymine. I wonder if it's just a syntactic thing for Rubymine in the code completion. If you use the `welcome_user_path` completion does it result in the correct path being generated in the html sent to the browser?

Comment: In my example, `welcome_user_path` is incorrect and throws an error. `welcome_users_path` is not recognized by rubymine (the editor says it should be without `s`), but it is the correct version and generates correctly the path.

Answer (score 0):

From the JetBrains Bug Tracker:

[wrong name resolved from routes.rb by inspector and code hint in view](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/RUBY-11949)

This bug was for version 4.5.2 and marked as resolved. What version are you on? If you are on a newer version I would file a new bug report with them. Or update to the latest version if you are not on it already.

Comment: I have updated to version 5.4.3.2.1 and the problem is still there.

Comment: I have opened a new bug report with JetBrains for this issue.